# Calculate difference between values in linear order using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

The best way to describe this without knowing Python or VB jargon is to add these screenshots. I would like to emulate this Excel calculation in ArcMap10.1. MEAS is the distance along my route and ET_Z is the elevation at the route vertex. I just need the difference from the next point down the line from the previous one.

[image: Excel calculation]

I'm not sure the best approach to this, but figured that there may be simple Python solution for this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to answer this without code but in model builder then a solution is on the ESRI forum site [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/76833-Calculate-the-difference-between-rows-in-a-single-field-Can-Field-Calculator-do-it?highlight=calculate%20difference).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use the model to suit my needs and it worked perfectly! I tested it with 2 datasets. The first contained 377 records which took 76 seconds. The second dataset contained 11,500 records and it took 2 hours. This is perfect for smaller datasets. Email me if you would like to have the model...